# Clear screen only on first command buffer at vulkan api

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, vulkan

I try to realize multithreaded rendering with vulkan api.I build a multiple command buffers from other threads. Then execute them.But since there is have a clear screen in every command buffer, I don't get picture.

```
VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo{};
beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;

VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo{};
renderPassInfo.sType                = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
renderPassInfo.renderPass           = m_pRenderPass;
renderPassInfo.framebuffer          = m_swapChainFrameBufferPtrs[m_nImageIndex];
renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset    = { 0, 0 };
renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent    = { m_nWidth, m_nHeight };

std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues{};
clearValues[0].color            = { {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f} };
clearValues[1].depthStencil     = { 1.0f, 0 };
renderPassInfo.clearValueCount  = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size());
renderPassInfo.pClearValues     = clearValues.data();

VkViewport viewport{...};
VkRect2D scissor{...};

CFrameCommandBuffer& currentFrame = m_frames[m_nCurrentFrame];

for (std::uint32_t n = 0; n < currentFrame.m_commandBufferPtrs.size(); ++n)
{
    auto& pCmdBuffer = currentFrame.m_commandBufferPtrs[n];

    vkResetCommandBuffer(pCmdBuffer, 0);
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(pCmdBuffer, &beginInfo);
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(pCmdBuffer, &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    vkCmdSetViewport(pCmdBuffer, 0, 1, &viewport);
    vkCmdSetScissor(pCmdBuffer, 0, 1, &scissor);
}
```

If I don't use screen clearing for the second and subsequent buffers.

```
renderPassInfo.clearValueCount  = 0;
renderPassInfo.pClearValues     = nullptr;
```

I get an error:

```
In vkCmdBeginRenderPass the VkRenderPassBeginInfo struct has a clearValueCount of 0 but there must be at least 2 entries in pClearValues array to account for the highest index attachment in VkRenderPass 0x1ebe0f000000012a[] that uses VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR is 2. Note that the pClearValues array is indexed by attachment number so even if some pClearValues entries between 0 and 1 correspond to attachments that aren't cleared they will be ignored.
```

How can I clear screen correctly only at first command buffer ?

Answer (score 1):

When calling `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` you are required a set of values to clear the render pass attachments.

> `pClearValues` is a pointer to an array of `clearValueCount` `VkClearValue` structures containing clear values for each attachment, if the attachment uses a `loadOp` value of `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` or if the attachment has a depth/stencil format and uses a `stencilLoadOp` value of `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR`. The array is indexed by attachment number. Only elements corresponding to cleared attachments are used. Other elements of `pClearValues` are ignored.<sup>[1](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap8.html#VkRenderPassBeginInfo) [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20220716131307/https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap8.html#VkRenderPassBeginInfo)</sup>

When creating the `VkRenderPass` object you specified whether you wanted each attachment cleared in the [`VkRenderPassCreateInfo`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap8.html#VkRenderPassCreateInfo) stucture. If you don't want to clear the attachment at the beginning of a render pass then you need to set the `loadOp` of each of the [`VkAttachmentDescription`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap8.html#VkAttachmentDescription) to [`VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3/html/chap8.html#VkAttachmentLoadOp).